# Adding users to WSO2 Identity Server using SOAP API without specifying a password

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are using the WSO2 Identity Server SOAP API to add users. Is there way to add a user without specifying a password in the SOAP Envelope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users can login to WSO2 Carbon management console by providing username/password. Also external system can access admin services of Carbon server by providing username/password.

> Is there any ways to extend the default authentication mechanism ?

Yes. WSO2 Carbon product provides an authentication framework that can be used to extend the different authentication mechanism. By default WSO2 Carbon product is shipped with several authenticators. Some authenitcators only use for access the admin service APIs. Some are only for access management console login…..  You can find more details about WSO2 Authentication framework from here

Following are currently available authenticators

1. IWA Authenticator  :  Once user is login in to the windows server machine using windows authentication,  User can seamlessly login to the WSO2 Carbon management console. WSO2 Carbon product must be configured with AD
2. SAML2 SSO Authenticator  :  Once user tries to access WSO2 Carbon management console, user would be redirected to configured IDP.  User only provides credentials to the IDP and would be able to login to Carbon management console seamlessly. But here,  IDP and WSO2 Carbon product must have the same user for authorization purpose. Therefore sometime, same user store can be shared with IDP and Carbon products.
3. WebSeal Authenticator   :   User has already login to WebSeal server,  when user tried to login to  Carbon management console.  User can login seamlessly. But here,  IDP and WSO2 Carbon product must have the same user for authorization purpose
4. Mutual SSL  :  This is not used to login to  management console.  But this is used to access Admin service APIs of Carbon server.

For more details, check [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/03/25/different-authentication-mechanism-for-wso2-carbon-management-console-and-admin-service-apis/)